# How to install postgresql on heroku?

Tags: wordpress, postgresql, heroku

I want to install wordpress on heroku and follow this tutorial(https://github.com/mhoofman/wordpress-heroku) I downloaded the toolbelt of heroku and got the git repo on my disk I also created a heroku account but when I want to add postgresql to it i get:

```
$ heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev
 !    autoupdate in progress
 !    No app specified.
 !    Run this command from an app folder or specify which app to use with --app
 <app name>
```

Why I do everything as stated in the tutorial;?

I appreciate your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it!!! I thought to complicated!!! I had to create an app first;P

Comment: maximus was right. Heroku is not like a normal machine that you can install a library and share it to everything. It's a per-app-based system.